# Get a button inside tableview cell to run the same as didSelectCell

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, uibutton

I have a tableview with a UIButton within the cell.

I have created some functionality within didSelectRowAtIndexPath. What I would like is for the same functionality/method to run when the user clicks on the button too.

How can I make the buttonPressed method run the didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

If I cannot do this, I can move the functionality to a new method and have both call this new method. However, how do I get the cell indexPath from the button pressed method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button pressed");
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
    UITableView *curTableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [curTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    [self didSelectRowOrButtonAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

I made a new method didSelectRowOrButtonAtIndexPath and called this from both the buttonPressed and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and pass in the indexpath to be used in my method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the `UITableViewCell` object that contains the button (must be one of its container views, just go up the superview chain).
2. Find the indexPath with `[UITableView indexPathForCell:]`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, assign `indexPath.row` to your button's `tag` (assuming that you only need the row - the idea is to attach the `indexPath` to the button somehow, `tag` is just one way to do it).

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    // Init / Reuse the cell ...

    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button {
    [self method:button.tag];
}
```